# SharePoint 2010 - Strange errors starting this morning

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, web-services, error, troubleshooting

A few hours ago, one of the site owners sent me an email saying that they "couldn't click on anything".  Upon more inspection, it turns out that they do not have access to the ribbon bar, cannot click the Site Actions button, and cannot click the user menu (top-right of screen, when you click your username to go to My Sites, and such).

I removed the site owner from the Site Owners group, added her to Visitors, and confirmed that she still had the issue.  I then progressively moved him up into Members, and then Owners again, and still no luck.  Adding him to the User Policy on the web application (full control) didn't work, either.

The site owner follows this up with an email saying that she is getting this message:

> > Message: '_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames' is undefined 
> >     Line: 131 
> >     Char: 1
> >     Code: 0 
> >     URI: 
> >     https://sharepoint.com/IT/Pages/default.aspx
> >
> > Message: '_spBodyOnLoadCalled' is undefined
> >     Line: 151
> >     Char: 98
> >     Code: 0
> >     URI: https://sharepoint.com/IT/Pages/default.aspx
> >
> > Message: Object expected
> >     Line: 795
> >     Char: 1
> >     Code: 0
> >     URI: https://sharepoint.com/IT/Pages/default.aspx
> >
> > Message: 'ContextInfo' is undefined
> >     Line: 1179
> >     Char: 7
> >     Code: 0
> >     URI: https://sharepoint.com/IT/Pages/default.aspx

and this continues for about 20 or so errors.  Some of them give a URIs pointing to scripts:

> https://sharepoint.com/IT/Pages//_layouts/1033/ie55up.js?rev=aLkCI%2BqMbk0%2BXpjAY7eBc
>
> https://sharepoint.com/IT/Pages/_layouts/sp.core.js?rev=7ByNlH%2BvcgRJg%2BRCctdC0w%3D
>   %3D

And then they pointed me to some errors like...

> SCRIPT5009: '_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames' is undefined 
>   Home.aspx, line 990 character 76
>
> SEC7115: :visited and :link styles can only differ by color. Some styles
>   were not applied to :visited. 
>   Home.aspx
>
> SCRIPT5007: The value of the property 'RegisterSod' is null or undefined,
>   not a Function object 
>   Home.aspx, line 1063 character 1

The last email I received said that the person reporting these problems says that he can't see any calendar entries in any of the sites.  What the heck?

All of these problems are apparently being experienced by everyone, except for me.  And my user account has no administrative privileges...I use an admin account for that.

Needless to say, I'm pretty stumped on what to check first.  I've never had to deal with script errors as I never see them (I'm not a web developer, just a system admin who happens to have an MCTS in configuring SharePoint 2010).  I've spent a few hours looking into what happened and how to fix it, but so far have seen nothing in the ULS logs, and the server event logs show "normal" errors that I already know about.

Does anyone have an idea of where I should start troubleshooting this?  Is there a way to check to see if it was a master page that got changed somehow?

Comment: What browser do they and you use? Also, do other pages work?

Comment: If you check SharePoint Designer of the site or http://sharepointsite/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx, you should see if any MasterPages were modified, and by who.

Comment: @JamesLove Everyone uses Internet Explorer 8 (version 8.0.7600).

Comment: @Mike thank you!  I checked, yet the only non-"System Account" that edited the master pages was one employee who is no longer here, and t he date was July of 2010.  So that wouldn't be it, as it's 2 years and 1 month late!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are having a javascript related issue.  Are there any custom scripts referenced from those pages?  If part of the custom script is broken it can interfere with the standard scripts and methods.

If the publishing features are activated on this site be sure that any javascript files stored in the site assets or related libraries are all fully published.  In some cases I've seen this case inconsistent behavior based on the level of the user.

Comment: how would I determine if there are any custom scripts referenced in those pages?  I have access to SharePoint Designer 2010, but have very little experience with it (mainly just creating a workflow, and poking around in a test site occasionally).  It is actually happening all over the farm, and isn't specific to just one site collection.  I have a test site that I use occasionally, and had some of my team members access it, and they experience the same thing that the site owner who reported it to me did.

Comment: Could be challenging if you aren't sure what you are looking for.  I would start by checking to see if the masterpage had been altered.  If there was a script reference added there, it would impact all sites/pages that use that MasterPage.  If you have a clean copy of v4.master you can compare to see which .js references might have been added.  As described above, I would also check out the site assets library if publishing features are used.  I would also use something like the IE Toolbar or Firebug to review the page info.

Comment: I found out where the Site Assets library was (in SPD2010) and check there, but it was empty.  This was on the site of the first person to notify me, so I'll drill down and check all 50-ish subsites there, to see if there is anything different, and then move on to other site collections and see if those were edited as well.  

I really dislike errors that aren't there on day, but show up the next, especially when it's something that nobody in the farm really uses.  The "busiest" customer we have uses InfoPath, but other than that the users we have are quiet sheep grazing on pasture...

Comment: I wonder if it could be something with the proxy rules?  The department that normally handles updates to the proxy isn't very forthcoming to other teams (even though we work for the same customer on the contract), and the last time they "blocked" something it was _vit/bin which caused a big mess with document check-ins and check-outs.  I'll contact them to see if anything was recently pushed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpful posts!  It actually turned out to be something unrelated to SharePoint - the reverse proxy on the network had rules changed that were blocking some JavaScript functions, which is why many of the errors were JS based...go figure!  I really wish the network team here where I work would follow our advice and create a distro list and add any and all system admins to it so that we know what they're doing and how it's going to impact us.../sigh.

Comment: So then you can mark this as answer:)